# How this part of code in asp.net mvc controller can be optimized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net mvc 3. Situation:

I have model class "Event"

```
public class Event 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Period Plan { get; set; }
    public Period Fact { get; set; }
}

public class Period
{
    public bool isPeriod { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

And ActionResult method "Example" in controller. In this method I have list< Event> collection and I need to get dictionary< DateTime, int> from list< Event>. DateTime - some date, int - number of events on this date. The event can last for several days(isPeriod=1) or for only one (isPeriod=0). Also there are some restrictions on dates of events, which should be added (dateFrom, dateTo).

I wrote some part of code, which work for this situation, but it looks not good. Some parts of the code are repeated many times. What can be done to optimize this part of the code? Maybe here can be used LINQ or something else to get result in easier way?

```
public ActionResult Example()
{
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

    ...

    Dictionary<DateTime, int> days = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();   //Dictionary which I need in result 

    Dictionary<DateTime, HashSet<string>> dic = new Dictionary<DateTime, HashSet<string>>();    //this dictionary is used in foreach cycle

    foreach (var ev in events)
    {
        //plan
        //exact date
        if (!ev.Plan.isPeriod)
        {

            if (ev.Plan.From >= dateFrom && ev.Plan.From <= dateTo)
            {
                if (!dic.ContainsKey(ev.Plan.From))
                {
                    dic.Add(ev.Plan.From, new HashSet<string>());
                    dic[ev.Plan.From].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    dic[ev.Plan.From].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        //period
        else
        {
            //period is between dateFrom and dateTo
            if (ev.Plan.From >= dateFrom && ev.Plan.To <= dateTo)
            {
                for (DateTime date = ev.Plan.From; date <= ev.Plan.To; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(date))
                    {
                        dic.Add(date, new HashSet<string>());
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            //period begins before dateFrom
            else if (ev.Plan.From < dateFrom && ev.Plan.To <= dateTo)
            {
                for (DateTime date = dateFrom; date <= ev.Plan.To; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(date))
                    {
                        dic.Add(date, new HashSet<string>());
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            //period ends after dateTo
            else if (ev.Plan.From >= dateFrom && ev.Plan.To > dateTo)
            {
                for (DateTime date = ev.Plan.From; date <= dateTo; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(date))
                    {
                        dic.Add(date, new HashSet<string>());
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //fact
        //exact date
        if (!ev.Fact.isPeriod)
        {
            if (ev.Fact.From >= dateFrom && ev.Fact.From <= dateTo)
            {
                if (!dic.ContainsKey(ev.Fact.From))
                {
                    dic.Add(ev.Fact.From, new HashSet<string>());
                    dic[ev.Fact.From].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    dic[ev.Fact.From].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        //period 
        else
        {
            //period is between dateFrom and dateTo
            if (ev.Fact.From >= dateFrom && ev.Fact.To <= dateTo)
            {
                for (DateTime date = ev.Fact.From; date <= ev.Fact.To; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(date))
                    {
                        dic.Add(date, new HashSet<string>());
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            //period begins before dateFrom
            else if (ev.Fact.From < dateFrom && ev.Fact.To <= dateTo)
            {
                for (DateTime date = dateFrom; date <= ev.Fact.To; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(date))
                    {
                        dic.Add(date, new HashSet<string>());
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            //period ends after dateTo
            else if (ev.Fact.From >= dateFrom && ev.Fact.To > dateTo)
            {
                for (DateTime date = ev.Fact.From; date <= dateTo; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
                {
                    if (!dic.ContainsKey(date))
                    {
                        dic.Add(date, new HashSet<string>());
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //getting result Dictionary
        foreach (var d in dic)
        {
            days.EventsCount[d.Key] = d.Value.Count();
        }
    }

    return View(days);
}
```

Comment: `list<Event> events = new list<Event>();
` does this compile? Please add your code.

Comment: @BhushanFirake Why that will not compile? What's wrong?

Comment: The new **lower case** list ? :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Notice case of `list`..

Comment: @BhushanFirake Good catch. I thought `Event` is okay but `event` won't compile. but missed small `list`

Comment: This code will not compile you have semicolon inside if  if(DateTime date = ev.Fact.From; date <= ev.Fact.To; date = date.AddDays(1.0))

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I see ...take out the following code into a separate method.

```
          if (!dic.ContainsKey(date))
            {
                dic.Add(date, new HashSet<string>());
                dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                dic[date].Add(ev.Key.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Keeping the code in a separate method is not called optimization.

Comment: This won't optimize, but definitely make the code more readable.

Comment: @BhushanFirake From question: `*Some parts of the code are repeated many times. What can be done to optimize this part of the code?*` Maybe wrong wording, but doesn't deserve a -1. A +1 to offset

Comment: He got repeated code and when he say optimization is he want to avoid repeats in this sense because code will not be that much concern of a pefomance

Answer (score 3):

You need to write down what you are trying to do in pseudo-code. This is too complicated. I would recommend moving a lot of the logic to the `Event` class, possibly create two subclasses of the `Event` class, to handle the `isPeriod` case.

In summary, you need to extract methods, and perform the "Replace type code with subclass" refactoring (where "typecode" in your case is the `isPeriod` property).

(see e.g. http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-type-code-with-subclasses)

Answer (score 1):

You should extract this code into a `testable unit`, [write unit tests](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.2.10) against the code, and then start to refactor and optimize safe in the knowledge that you have tests that will capture anything you have inadvertently broken.

[The Art Of Unit Testing](http://artofunittesting.com/) is a good resource.

[Principles and Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Principles-Patterns-Practices-Robert-Martin/dp/0131857258) is also a good book for refactoring, and the first few chapters goes through a refactoring scenario.